# Maximum execution time using cURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm getting the error 
        Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

which is odd because I have the timeout set to 0.

```
    function curl(){

        $this->options = Array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,   
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => FALSE, 
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 0, 
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0, 
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 20, 
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => random_user_agent(), 
        CURLOPT_URL => $this->url, 
      );

       $this->ch = curl_init(); //Initalising curl;
     curl_setopt_array($this->ch, $this->options); 
     $this->data = curl_exec($this->ch); // Executing cURL;
     curl_close($this->ch);


     return $this->data;
     }
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem may be?

Many thanks in advance for any responses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specifying 0 basically [eliminates the timeout](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TIMEOUT.html) of the cUrl request.

However, the PHP script itself is not allowed to run for more than [30 seconds (by default](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)). So if the request takes more than 30 seconds, the PHP script itself will be terminated, resulting in the message you get, regardless whether it was cUrl or just another piece of code that caused the script to take that long.

Comment: I've had the same results when I've set the timeout to -> 500 , 5000etc.. Do you think I need to change the setting within php.ini? Many thanks for your response.

Comment: Yes. Setting the timeout of the curl request doesn't help. You should set the time limit of the PHP script itself. I provided a link in the question. You can change php.ini or use the `set_time_limit` function.

Comment: You're awesome. Thanks again.